# ForbiddenException in AssistantSimpleExample, with java-SDK

Tags: watson-assistant

I tried the first example in https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-api-client, but whatever assistantID I used, it show me the same exception:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   com.ibm.cloud.sdk.core.service.exception.ForbiddenException: Forbidden
>     at
>   com.ibm.cloud.sdk.core.service.BaseService.processServiceCall(BaseService.java:371)
>     at
>   com.ibm.cloud.sdk.core.service.BaseService$WatsonServiceCall.execute(BaseService.java:419)
>     at AssistantSimpleExample.main(AssistantSimpleExample.java:31)

What can I do for that?

Answer (score 2):

I need to add this:

service.setServiceUrl("https://gateway-syd.watsonplatform.net/assistant/api");

Then it solved.

Comment: I had to add regional path, but thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction +1